# Preprocessor "macro function" vs. function pointer - best practice?

Tags: c

I recently started a small personal project (RGB value to BGR value conversion program) in C, and I realised that a function that converts from RGB to BGR can not only perform the conversion but also the inversion.  Obviously that means I don't really need two functions `rgb2bgr` and `bgr2rgb`.  However, does it matter whether I use a function pointer instead of a macro?  For example:

```
int rgb2bgr (const int rgb);

/*
 * Should I do this because it allows the compiler to issue
 * appropriate error messages using the proper function name,
 * not to mention possible debugging benefits?
 */
int (*bgr2rgb) (const int bgr) = rgb2bgr;

/*
 * Or should I do this since it is merely a convenience
 * and they're really the same function anyway?
 */
#define bgr2rgb(bgr) (rgb2bgr (bgr))
```

I'm not necessarily looking for a change in execution efficiency as it's more of a subjective question out of curiosity.  I am well aware of the fact that type safety is neither lost nor gained using either method.  Would the function pointer merely be a convenience or are there more practical benefits to be gained of which I am unaware?

Comment: Personally I'd just come up with a name that describes both uses, like `int swap_rb()` ;)

Comment: @caf: Definitely another great idea.  It completely avoids the issue, but it is a logically sound alternative.  +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility would be to just have the second function call the first and let the compiler worry about optimizing it (by inlining or generating a tail call).

Comment: Good idea.  After all, why should I try to create better code than my optimizing compiler?  It doesn't really change the behaviour overall, just the underlying machine instructions.  For the record, I didn't really save any bytes by using a function pointer, a macro or a subroutine that calls the real function after stripping the binary/executable of unneeded items.  In the end, the compiler just had three bytes changed (yes, only three), so as far as optimization goes, I can't do any better than I already have without resorting to making my code less portable using inline assembly. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

I would use the macro. It's more common and more idiomatic, and runs into fewer problems crossing translation units (i.e. you don't have to worry about declaring the macro static).

Additionally, by using a function pointer, you prevent inlining on most compilers.

Finally, with the function pointer, it's possible for clients to do this:

```
int evil(const int bgr) { /* Do something evil */ }

bgr2rgb = evil
```

Sure, they probably don't want this, but it's possible there could be a variable named similar to `bgr2rgb` down the line where it only takes one typo....

The macro is safer, though I would define it this way -- there's no need for a function-like macro here:

```
#define bgr2rgb rgb2bgr
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the loss of function inlining. It's definitely something worth knowing! Also, I could obviously `const`-qualify the function pointer, preventing it from being re-assigned to another function. As for using a macro that isn't function-like, I don't see any benefit to that, though I can certainly imagine a problem where something ridiculous like `int bgr2rgb = 0;` is possible. In terms of safety, a function-like macro is better because it avoids such an issue. After all, not all macros have such strange names. Great input overall! I hope there are more thoughtful answers!

Comment: The function-like macro is better, because it means you can still have a struct member called `bgr2rgb` without getting odd results.

Comment: @caf: I agree, but with a function-like macro, you can't assign the function bgr2rgb to a function pointer.  Using Dustin's first method is better since it avoids both macro problems.